# can't load template to route using ui-router from sidebar

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am a newbee to angular. in my web app i have a side bar loaded in a ui-view from template in the index page and there is another ui-view where i want to load template clicking links from the side bar. here are my codes and templates...please help me...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
 </head>
 <body ng-app="testapp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4" ui-view="sidebar">
     
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8" ui-view="content">
     
    </div>
   </div>
  </div> 



 <!-- Javascript links and scripts -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.2/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  var app = angular.module('testapp', ['ui.router']);

  /*route configuration*/
  app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');

    $stateProvider.state('home',{
     views:{
      'sidebar':{templateUrl:'sidebar.html'}, 
      'content':{templateUrl:'default.main.html'},     
     }
    });
    $stateProvider.state('home.page02',{
     views:{
      'content@home':{templateUrl:'page02.html'},
     }
    });

   }]);

  /*main controller at index page*/
  app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope','$state', function ($scope,$state) {
   $state.go('home');
   
  }]);


 </script>

 </body>
</html>
```

```html
<ul>
 <li>home</li>
 <li>page01</li>
 <li><a href="#" ui-sref=".page02">page02</a></li>
</ul>
```

```html
<h2>Page 01 is here!</h2>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ui-routing we can use ui-sref which takes the complete state name as its value
for example:

```
<li><a href="#" ui-sref="home.page02">page02</a></li>
```

and the controller should be like:

```
var app = angular.module('testapp', ['ui.router']);

        /*route configuration*/
        app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
                $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');

                $stateProvider
                .state('home',{
                    views:{
                        'sidebar':{templateUrl:'sidebar.html'}, 
                        'content':{templateUrl:'default.main.html'},                    
                    }
                })
                .state('home.page02',{
                    views:{
                        'content@home':{templateUrl:'page02.html'},
                    }
                });

            }]);

        /*main controller at index page*/
        app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope','$state', function ($scope,$state) {
            $state.go('home');

        }]);
```

Comment: thanks....but my solution is in the reply...plz check and tell whether it is correct...

Comment: yup...I hope it should be working fine with the solution u provided in reply

Comment: [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views) is the link which may help you for looking in to named views

Answer (score 0):

```
<li><a href="#" ui-sref=".page02">page02</a></li>
```

`ui-sref` must contain a state name. if you want to go to `home.page02` it should be

```
<li><a href="#" ui-sref="home.page02">page02</a></li>
```

and no need to give every time `$stateProvider.state()`
Just do it like

```
$stateProvider
           .state('home', {url: '', template: ''})
           .state('home.page02', {url: '', template: ''})
```

And `named-views` usage https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views go through the link provided. It is awesome

Answer (score 0):

i changed the script...

```js
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');

    $stateProvider
    .state('home',{
     views:{
      'sidebar':{templateUrl:'sidebar.html'}, 
      'content':{templateUrl:'default.main.html'},     
     }
    })
    .state('home.page02',{
     views:{
      'content@':{templateUrl:'page02.html'},
     }
    });

   }]);
```